# Is there a way to use regex to find the substring between two strings?

Tags: python, regex

I know it may seem like this question has already been asked, but I've tried searching and using the other answers for my example but for some reason, I can't seem to get it working.

I have the text:

```
    ['root(ROOT-0, love-2) s1', 'amod(perve-5, good-4) s2',
    'advmod(love-2, thanks-12) s3', 'amod(mags-16, glossy-15) s4']
```

And I only want the text in between amod( up until the -.
for example, I want:

```
'perve' and 'mags'
```

I've tried:

```
words = re.findall('\((.*?)\-', v)
```

but it returns:

```
['ROOT', 'perve', 'love', 'mags']
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You may use; `r'amod\(([^-]*)-'`

Comment: If `amod` is always going to be there and you're looking for the text right after it, then include the text `'amod'` in your regex pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use:

```
>>> test_str = ("    ['root(ROOT-0, love-2) s1', 'amod(perve-5, good-4) s2',\n"
...     "    'advmod(love-2, thanks-12) s3', 'amod(mags-16, glossy-15) s4']")
>>>
>>> print ( re.findall(r"amod\(([^-]*)-", test_str) )
['perve', 'mags']
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kBYGe8/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `amod`: Match literal text `amid(`
- `([^-]*)`: Match 0 or more of any characters that are not `-` and capture it in group #1
- `-`: Match a literal `-`

Comment: Thanks a lot. This helped me understand how to use r to match literal text.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do the trick as regex :

`(?<=amod\().+?(?=-)`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kNkz1j/2)

Answer (score 0):

When I want to find an arbitrary substring between two known substrings, I usually rely on a combination of a lookahead and lookbehind assertion.

```py
for string in List:
    match = re.search(r'(?<=amod\()[^-]+(?=-)',string).group()
    print(match)
```

Note, that you have to use `[^-]` (everything except minus), because of the lookbehind assertion `(?=-)`. You can't use your greedy `.+` and then expect the regex to stop matching at your lookbehind, if your lookbehind (-) is also in the greedy match (.+)

Hope this is what you wanted.